# jQuery: Not able to read to xml element value

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "vector.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
                            $(xml).find('Vector').each(function() {
                            //var attrVal = $(this).find('VectorType').attr('tc');
                            var intialVal = $('this').find('InitialValue').text();
                            var attrVal = $(this).find('VectorMode').attr('tc');
                            alert(intialVal);

                        }); 
                }
            });
    });
```

XML looks like this:

```
<Values>
        <Result>
          <ResultBasis>
            <Vector>
              <VectorType tc="71"></VectorType>
              <VectorBaseDate>2012-06-16</VectorBaseDate>
              <InitialValue>150000</InitialValue>
            </Vector>
            <Vector tc="T20V09">
              <VectorType tc="71"></VectorType>
              <VectorBaseDate>2012-06-16</VectorBaseDate>
              <InitialValue>150000</InitialValue>
            </Vector>
            <Vector>
              <VectorType tc="5"></VectorType>
              <VectorBaseDate>2012-06-16</VectorBaseDate>
              <VectorMode tc="4"></VectorMode>
              <InitialValue>102.47</InitialValue>
            </Vector>
            <Vector>
              <VectorType tc="5"></VectorType>
              <VectorBaseDate>2012-06-16</VectorBaseDate>
              <VectorMode tc="3"></VectorMode>
              <InitialValue>307.42</InitialValue>
            </Vector>
```

Here I am able to attribute values of `VectorType` and `VectorMode` elements but  no luck with `InitialValue` and `VectorBaseDate` elements value.

```
alert(var intialVal = $('this').find('InitialValue').val());
```

give me `undefined` and

```
alert(var intialVal = $('this').find('InitialValue').text());
```

gives me empty alert statements.

```
Note: <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the jQuery version, but I do know in Javascript it is nodeValue that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this` instead of `'this'`

```
var intialVal = $(this).find('InitialValue').text();
```